# Как добавить пагинатор к таблице в Django

Tags: html, django, шаблоны, pagination

У меня есть таблица с содержимым и надо добавить к ней пагинацию в файлы: views.py, и шаблон самой таблицы. Уже заискался в интернете и так ничего толкового не нашел, как и на ютубе. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
def geting_posts(request):
    get_posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/db_table.html', {'get_posts':get_posts})
```

Это код без добавления пагинатора.
А это шаблон:

```
<div class = 'features' id = 'content'>
    <!-- {% block content %} -->
    <table style = 'border: 1px solid #000;'>
        <tr>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid #000;">ID of Post</th>
            <th style = 'border: 1px solid #000;'>Title of Post</th>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid #000;">Text of Post</th>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid #000;">Updating</th>
            <th style = "border: 1px solid #000;">Deleting</th>
        </tr>
    {% for post in get_posts %}
        <tr style = 'border: 1px solid #000;'>
            <td>{{post.id}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'post_details' post.id %}">
                    {{post.title}}
                </a>
            </td>   
            <td>{{post.description}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'update_post' post.id %}">
                    Редактировать
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'delete_post' post.id %}">
                    Удалить
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <a href="{% url 'create_posts' %}">
        <button>
            Создать пост
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать класс ListView из django.views.generic и там указать свойство paginate_by(сколько записей будет на одной странице),но если не хотите использовать класс, то для функции это можно сделать так:

```
from django.core.paginator import *
def fucntion(request):
    contact_list = Contact.objects.all() #список для пагинации
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # сколько записей на 1 странице

    page_number = request.GET.get('page') #GET параметр page 
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

А в шаблоне все будет одинаково, так и для класса, так и для функции:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul style="" class="pagination justify-content-center">
      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Пред</a></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% for page in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page == page_obj.number %}
            <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{page}}">{{page}}</a></li>    
        {% elif page > page_obj.number|add:-3 and page < page_obj.number|add:3 %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{page}}">{{page}}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}">След</a></li>
      {% endif %}
      
    </ul>
  </nav>
```